# Can't run git from command line

Tags: command-line, git

I'm getting the error

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

When trying to run git from the cmd in wwindows 7

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed a git client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the git client. If it still isn't working add `C:\program files\git\bin` to your PATH environment variable.